# Как получить последний элемент из JSON на PHP?

Tags: php, json

Здравствуйте, как получить последний элемент из `json`? Я сделал следующее.

Цель этого всего заключается в том что бы получить последнее сообщения от последнего пользователя который его прислал и отправить его обратно.

```
<?php
#include('bots.php');

$botTokken = "токен";
$website = 'https://api.telegram.org/bot'.$botTokken.'';

$update = file_get_contents($website."/getupdates");

$updateArray = json_decode($update,true);
$val count($updateArray['result']);
#$fruit = $updateArray;

$chadId = $updateArray["result"][1]["message"]["chat"]["id"]; #chatId 
$text = $updateArray["result"][1]["message"]["text"]; #text 
$message_id = $updateArray["result"][1]["message"]["message_id"]; #msg_id 



#$send = $website.'/sendmessage?chat_id='.$chadId.'&text='.$text.'';
$send = $website.'/sendmessage?disable_web_page_preview=true&chat_id='.$chadId.'&reply_to_message_id='.$message_id.'&text='.$text.'';

#file_get_contents($send);

print_r($send);
echo "<br>";
print_r($text);
echo "<br>";
print_r($message_id);
echo "<br>";
print_r($chadId);
echo "<br>";




?>
<script type="text/javascript">
    // начать повторы с интервалом 2 сек
var timerId = setInterval(function() {

}, 2000);

// через 5 сек остановить повторы
setTimeout(function() {
  clearInterval(timerId);
  window.location.href = "http://localhost:8443/bot.php"
}, 7000);

</script>
```

Вот json данные которые я получаю и формирую в массив

> {"ok":true,"result":[{"update_id":431496985,
>   "message":{"message_id":4,"from":{"id":122515753,"first_name":"Malyshev","last_name":"Ruvim"},"chat":{"id":122515753,"first_name":"Malyshev","last_name":"Ruvim","type":"private"},"date":1448216109,"text":"qdw"}},{"update_id":431496986,
>   "message":{"message_id":5,"from":{"id":122515753,"first_name":"Malyshev","last_name":"Ruvim"},"chat":{"id":122515753,"first_name":"Malyshev","last_name":"Ruvim","type":"private"},"date":1448216109,"text":"q"}},{"update_id":431496987,
>   "message":{"message_id":6,"from":{"id":122515753,"first_name":"Malyshev","last_name":"Ruvim"},"chat":{"id":122515753,"first_name":"Malyshev","last_name":"Ruvim","type":"private"},"date":1448216109,"text":"wd"}},{"update_id":431496988,
>   "message":{"message_id":7,"from":{"id":122515753,"first_name":"Malyshev","last_name":"Ruvim"},"chat":{"id":122515753,"first_name":"Malyshev","last_name":"Ruvim","type":"private"},"date":1448216109,"text":"qdw"}},{"update_id":431496989,
>   "message":{"message_id":8,"from":{"id":122515753,"first_name":"Malyshev","last_name":"Ruvim"},"chat":{"id":122515753,"first_name":"Malyshev","last_name":"Ruvim","type":"private"},"date":1448216109,"text":"qw"}},{"update_id":431496990,
>   "message":{"message_id":9,"from":{"id":122515753,"first_name":"Malyshev","last_name":"Ruvim"}

Сейчас он выводит и отправляет только те сообщения и только тем пользователям кого я выберу по id.

```
$chadId = $updateArray["result"][id сейчас он 1]["message"]["chat"]["id"]; #chatId 
$text = $updateArray["result"][id сейчас он 1]["message"]["text"]; #text 
$message_id = $updateArray["result"][id сейчас он 1]["message"]["message_id"]; #msg_id
```

Comment: p.s не нужно мне кидать ссылки на api.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно узнать количество сообщений, то есть элементов в массиве `result`, и вызвать последний:

```
var_dump($arrMessage['result'][count($arrMessage['result']) - 1]);
```

Answer (score 3):

На самом деле, вычислять ID последнего элемента в массиве вовсе не обязательно. В PHP есть функция [`end`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.end.php), которая сдвигает внутренний указатель на последний элемент массива и возвращает этот элемент. Пример использования:

```
var_dump(end($updateArray['result']));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$array->reverse()[0]->print();
```

Comment: Старайтесь писать развернутые ответы